# Setup fancyindex on Alpine nginx docker image

Tags: docker, nginx, alpine-linux

I am trying to set up fancyindex on Nginx Alpine docker image. I have below

```
FROM nginx:alpine

RUN apk update

RUN apk add  nginx-mod-http-fancyindex \
        --repository https://alpine.global.ssl.fastly.net/alpine/edge/community \
        --repository https://alpine.global.ssl.fastly.net/alpine/edge/main \
        --repository https://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing

RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

EXPOSE 80

CMD [ "nginx" ]
```

In nginx.conf file on top I added a line like

```
load_module "/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_fancyindex_module.so";
```

But I see an error like

```
1#1: module "/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_fancyindex_module.so" version 1020001 instead of 1021000 in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: [emerg] module "/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_fancyindex_module.so" version 1020001 instead of 1021000 in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
```

How do I solve the problem? Am I in right path of setting fancyindex?

Comment: this one works: https://hub.docker.com/r/ajslater/nginx